# "code": "390100" Incorrect Username Password specified when trying to connect to SQL API from Postman using Oauth

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the below error when trying to make a connection to the snowflake.

```
{
    "code": "390100",
    "message": "Incorrect username or password was specified."
}
```

The same works well when I generate the token via cli and use the same to connect to snowflake. This issue is happening when I use Oauth.

Does any one has info on this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this error is seen when generating the token, right? If you can add some screenshots to illustrate the set up on Postman and provide details, it would be helpful to analyse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the official documentation below.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/submitting-requests.html#label-sql-api-submit-query-regionless-account

Snowflake-Account header must be passed and this must be the account locator (which you can find under your username when you connect to snowflake UI).

For example:

when you connect to snowflake, there are two URL's that can be utilized.

Regionless :--> https://organizationname-accountname.snowflakecomputing.com
With Region :-> https://Account_locator.us-east-2.snowflakecomputing.com

When you are using a Regionless URL and the authentication type as OAUTH, then you need to pass an additional header.

"Snowflake-Account: "

In postman you can pass the parameter under headers with key and value way, where key being Snowflake-Account and value being Account Locator.

If you don't use regionless URL, the above header is not needed.

Let me know if the above helps. Also attaching KB article for your reference  to setup with postman.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Connect-to-SQL-API-using-Postman